# the performance of php fread and echo is very bad

Tags: php, download, echo, fread

I write a php script named 'download.php' to push files to client,

```
$fd = fopen($path, "rb");
if ($fd === false) {
    echo "404 file not found";
    return false;
} 

Header("Content-type: image/png");

while (!feof($fd))
{
    $buf = fread($fd, 1024);
    if ($buf === false) {
        break;
    }
    echo $buf;
}

fclose($fd);
```

When I test on chrome to download a 4M image, it will consume 1.4s.
the apache server is on my PC. if I put the image in www/ and download it directly, that only consume 44ms.

I tried to increase the bufsize of fread, but it just improve performance a little.

Comment: Instead of reading and outputting chunks in a loop, try to simply use readfile.

Comment: @CBroe readfile will consume 643ms better than fread then echo, but still very long, and also readfile doesn't support partial download, is there any better method?

Comment: Consume what …?

Comment: @CBroe :-) I pressed `enter` when i'm editting, readfile cnsume 643ms

Comment: _“and also readfile doesn't support partial download”_ – neither does the code you have shown - so?

Comment: I read the manual of `readfile`, no paramters for offset and length, it just write all content of file to client. so I think it doen't support partial download, but now I mainly care the speed problem.

Comment: Yes. That is what that function does. But your code does not “support partial download” either - at least not what you have shown so far. To get that, you might want to use fseek first. But it probably won’t get much faster than that.

Comment: @CBroe I think i find the solution: [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)

Comment: Yes, if you have your own server, that might be the best option. (I heard in shared hosting environments this can easily cause security issues, so probably not a good fit for such situations.)

Comment: I have my server, i will try to add mod_xsendfile to my server. thanks for warmly your help.

Comment: it's my topology problem, the fopen and echo can reach (152 MB/s) but mod_xsendfile is much larger, can reach 231MB/s, maybe reach the I/O limit.

Answer (score 0):

fpassthru($fd) is a much more efficient way to pass the contents of a stream to php://output without loading the entire file contents into memory